# Back Button Functionality

Tags: jsp, struts2

I have a page which displays a list of orders that have been placed by a specific customer. When any one of the order links is clicked in that page, the customer will be re-directed to another page which displays the details of that specific order. I want a back button in that details page so that the user can come back to the order list page (i.e. to the page from which he was re-directed).. i want it to work exactly like the browser's back button.. I have searched a lot for this on Google but didnt succeed.. Pls help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JavaScript: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_his_back.asp

However, make sure to use HTTP redirects: http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/reback

Comment: Hi Stefan, thanks for the instant reply.. i did try out the example you specified but when i click on the back button, it displays a dialog box "Confirm Form Resubmission", in which case i need to click on the browser's refresh button.. Only then i will be redirected back to the page i came from.. How can i skip the extra step in between (i mean, i don't want the dialog box to appear. The user should be directly re-directed).. what am i missing out??

Comment: This is because you came to the overview page by submitting a form (add to cart or something similar). Then, when following a link and going back, the browser asks to resubmit the form (add to cart). You can circumvent this by redirecting the user from the page that is processing the initial form to the overview page: `form` -(submit)-> `processing w/o output` -(HTTP-redirect)-> `overview` -(link)-> `details`

Comment: This solution wont work if data changes by the time user clicks on back, this also is a security contraint in many application where you dont want your browser to cache your pages.